# Whats the alternative efficient method to retrieve the row index from data grid view with over 7000 + record in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

This is my current method. It's working right now but it is very inefficient. Can someone help me with an alternative to this?
P.S. Not the selected index. I am going to search for the recordID and then retrieve the row index of this recordID (tempProxyID) below.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
    Dim temp As String = row.Cells.Item(0).Value
    If temp.ToString.Trim = tempProxID Then
        rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(row.Index.ToString())
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Is the grid bound to a data source? If so, that's what you should be working with. If not, maybe it ought to be.

Comment: Not a good idea in first place to have a DGV with 7000+ row.

Comment: Try: `Dim rowIndex As Integer? = dgv.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Where(Function(a) a.Cells(0).Value.ToString = tempProxID).FirstOrDefault?.Index` Note that, the `rowIndex` is a Nullable of integer type so you need to check what the query returns through `rowIndex.HasValue` property.

Comment: Add an Exit For after you have found the index.

Comment: Why do you want to display that many records to a user. My index finger gets numb just thinking about it.

Comment: @Mary Thanks! I just want to know the way :)